# Change focus on next input after paste event with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events, jquery-events

I have got an HTML form with many input boxes. At the paste event on any of my input boxes I would like to set the focus on the following one. 
Here is the code I am currently using:

```
$("input").bind('paste', function(e) {
      var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
      //alert(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
      inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();      
      });
```

What happens with this code is the following. Let's say I have got input boxes "A" and "B". I paste a text into "A"; the function changes the focus on "B" and then save the text into "B". Nothing is pasted into "A".

Of course I would like the content to be pasted into "A" and then the focus switched to "B".

Is there a way to obtain this latter behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your paste event to trigger before changing focus, and so you need to finish your `bind` callback before calling the focus.

What you should do is to defer your focus call. You can use `setTimeout` and delay by 0 milliseconds - basically, call **after** your paste function ends.

```
$("input").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        inputs.eq( inputs.index(self)+ 1 ).focus();      
    }, 0)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6utcnaq3/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner. You just need to introduce some delay.

```
$("input").on('paste', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function () {
       $this
         .closest('form')
         .find('input')
         .eq($this.index() + 1)
         .focus();
   }, 100);    
});
```